# The operation was cancelled.. ErrorCode: 3072

Tags: office365, office365api, outlook-restapi

We are working on an iOS application that is using the MSOutlook-SDK-iOS version 2.0.1 to enable users
to send and receive work (Outlook) emails from the iOS app.  We registered the iOS app within the Microsoft Azure ActiveDirectory and specified 
Microsoft Graph (5 delegated permissions) and Office 365 Exchange Online (4 delegated permissions) permissions.  Here is the app manifest in Azure AD:

```
{
      "appId": "3b008367-4e7d-43e5-9a76-46a908e8fa65",
      "appRoles": [],
      "availableToOtherTenants": true,
      "displayName": "Chatbaka",
      "errorUrl": null,
      "groupMembershipClaims": null,
      "homepage": null,
      "identifierUris": [],
      "keyCredentials": [],
      "knownClientApplications": [],
      "logoutUrl": null,
      "oauth2AllowImplicitFlow": false,
      "oauth2AllowUrlPathMatching": false,
      "oauth2Permissions": [],
      "oauth2RequirePostResponse": false,
      "passwordCredentials": [],
      "publicClient": true,
      "replyUrls": [
      "url based on app name and iOS bundle id"
  ],
  "requiredResourceAccess": [
    {
      "resourceAppId": "00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000",
      "resourceAccess": [
        {
          "id": "14dad69e-099b-42c9-810b-d002981feec1",
          "type": "Scope"
        },
        {
          "id": "64a6cdd6-aab1-4aaf-94b8-3cc8405e90d0",
          "type": "Scope"
        },
        {
          "id": "e383f46e-2787-4529-855e-0e479a3ffac0",
          "type": "Scope"
        },
        {
          "id": "024d486e-b451-40bb-833d-3e66d98c5c73",
          "type": "Scope"
        },
        {
          "id": "570282fd-fa5c-430d-a7fd-fc8dc98a9dca",
          "type": "Scope"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "resourceAppId": "00000002-0000-0ff1-ce00-000000000000",
      "resourceAccess": [
        {
          "id": "2e83d72d-8895-4b66-9eea-abb43449ab8b",
          "type": "Scope"
        },
        {
          "id": "5eb43c10-865a-4259-960a-83946678f8dd",
          "type": "Scope"
        },
        {
          "id": "75767999-c7a8-481e-a6b4-19458e0b30a5",
          "type": "Scope"
        },
        {
          "id": "185758ba-798d-4b72-9e54-429a413a2510",
          "type": "Scope"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "samlMetadataUrl": null,
  "extensionProperties": [],
  "objectType": "Application",
  "objectId": "b49a326e-1053-4a34-92e3-453b7adecf1a",
  "deletionTimestamp": null,
  "createdOnBehalfOf": null,
  "createdObjects": [],
  "manager": null,
  "directReports": [],
  "members": [],
  "memberOf": [],
  "owners": [],
  "ownedObjects": []
}
```

The MSOutlook-SDK-iOS version 2.0.1 has dependencies on orc library version 0.20.3 and ADALiOS library version 1.2.4.
The iOS app is using the following authentication endpoints and resources:

```
static private let kRedirectURL = "based on app name and iOS bundle id"
// The Azure OAuth2 authority
static private let kAuthorityURL = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common"
// The resource identifier for the Outlook APIs
static private let kOutlookResourceURL = "https://outlook.office365.com"
// The client ID obtained by registering the app
static private let kClientId = "obtained from manually registering in Azure AD"
// API version url
static let kAPIUrl = "https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0"
```

We are noticing that some users are successfully able to get their work email in the iOS app while other users are experiencing authorization errors.

We have the following questions:

1. The MSOutlook-SDK-iOS version 2.0.1 was last updated 9 months ago https://github.com/OfficeDev/Outlook-SDK-iOS
    Do you have any plans to update the SDK?  If so when?  We are using CocoaPods to manage third party library dependencies.
2. For one of our users we are getting the following error from the iOS ADAL library : ERROR: authorization error. Additional Information: The operation was cancelled.. ErrorCode: 3072.   We added logic to change the ADAL logging level to verbose.
   Here is the log snippet:

   Could you provide more information on why the user is getting this error and how to fix it?

Comment: The log snippet is missing. And which line of code cause this issue? Is there helpful if log this account on other device? Or can you check whether it can get the messages successfully manually.

Comment: It fails in the ADALiOS when callingADALiOS [2016-08-17 22:51:43 - 24551610-7B4F-4428-9CB7-863A1ABCEAE0] VERBOSE: HTTP Protocol. Additional Information: HTTPProtocol::connection:willSendRequest:. Redirect response: (null). New request:https://clientauth1.amd.com/adfs/ls/?wfresh=0&wauth=http%3a%2f%2fschemas.microsoft.com%2fws%2f2008%2f06%2fidentity%2fauthenticationmethod%2fpassword&client-request-id=24551610-7b4f-4428-9cb7-863a1abceae0&username=jatang%40amd.com&wa=wsignin1.0&wtrealm=urn%3afederation%3aMicrosoftOnline&wctx=estsredirect%3d2%26estsrequest%[longsequenceoflettersandnumbershere]

Comment: If I open Safari mobile browser on the same iPhone and go to https://outlook.office365.com in the address bar and type in the same account details I can see the user's inbox successfully.

Comment: The authorization error log is from ADAuthenticationWebViewController.m in didFailLoadWithError line 210 but the actually call to cause it is from willSendRequest.  As far as I can tell on entering the user account details a redirect occurs and the user is treated as a federated user.  Not sure what federated user is?

Comment: @Amit patel could you able to find the answer?